# Reducing read time for reading DS18B20 temp sensors

Tags: programming, temperature-sensor

I have a number of temperature sensors connected up to an Arduino - I've split it into 3 sections, with each section having a 2-4 sensors on it (due to distances).   This works, but the code I'm using would seem to me to be very inefficient - particularly with respect of how long it takes to read all the sensors.

I've got 3 code blocks one after each other (which are modified from some code online) which look as below - save, of-course, for the name of the 1wire class.

```
// Dallas 1 Wire (Main Area):

 //  ds.reset_search();
 //  delay(250);
  while (ds.search(addr))
  {
    for( i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      Serial.print(addr[i], HEX);
    }

    if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
        Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
        return;
    }

    ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);
    ds.write(0x44, 0);        // start conversion, with parasite power on at the end

    delay(1000);     // maybe 750ms is enough, maybe not
    // we might do a ds.depower() here, but the reset will take care of it.

    present = ds.reset();
    ds.select(addr);    
    ds.write(0xBE);         // Read Scratchpad

    for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) {           // we need 9 bytes
      data[i] = ds.read();
    }
    raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
    if (type_s) {
      raw = raw << 3; // 9 bit resolution default
      if (data[7] == 0x10) {
        // "count remain" gives full 12 bit resolution
        raw = (raw & 0xFFF0) + 12 - data[6];
      }
    } else {
      byte cfg = (data[4] & 0x60);
      // at lower res, the low bits are undefined, so let's zero them
      if (cfg == 0x00) raw = raw & ~7;  // 9 bit resolution, 93.75 ms
      else if (cfg == 0x20) raw = raw & ~3; // 10 bit res, 187.5 ms
      else if (cfg == 0x40) raw = raw & ~1; // 11 bit res, 375 ms
      //// default is 12 bit resolution, 750 ms conversion time
    }
    celsius = (float)raw / 16.0;
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(celsius);
    Serial.print(",");
  }
```

I note that there is a 1000ms delay after each sensor is read, and I'm wondering if I can reduce this to a single 750ms delay for all the sensors.  My initial attempts to do this did not meet with success - but I confess that I can't quite get my head around the ds.reset, ds.select etc - and my initial attempts to do this have all failed.

Is it possible to remove this delay after reading each sensor ?

Comment: Which library do you use? [This one](http://milesburton.com/Main_Page?title=Dallas_Temperature_Control_Library) seems to do 'bulk' reading by default.

Comment: Reducing the bit resolution will reduce the time required, however some libraries get the resulting conversion entirely wrong, and need to be repaired if you do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After nearly a year and a number of experiments later, I've learned a little bit more about using these devices:

Issuing the sensors a Skip ROM command followed by Convert T command starts all devices converting temperature at once (pg.11 of the datasheet). Then you need only wait one delay period of {750,375,188,94}ms for a {12,11,10,9}-bit conversion, respectively, before you can start reading back the temperatures.

If the devices are being powered parasitically, the bus will need a strong pullup during the conversion; the 4.7KOhm pullup is not sufficient (pg.5 of the datasheet).

An arduino pin can source 40mA and I've found that a second pin directly bypassing the 4.7K pullup without the suggested transistor, will source enough current for at least 3 sensors (as many as I've tried so far) and I assume the technique could be extended to more pins. The strong pullup must be switched on within 10uSec after the Convert T command and kept on for the duration of the conversion. The 10uSec spec pretty much means you have to do this in the library.

I keep an abbreviated DS18B20 library around in which I assume the sensors on the bus are related, so it sets all of their resolutions at once and starts their conversions at once, and assumes that the bus is parasite-powered, which mine are, so it switches a specified pin as a strong pullup. I give up some flexibility that the full DSTemperature library would allow but it satisfies my temperature measuring requirements (so far) and simplifies my application code by black-boxing the above techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a search every time is quite inefficient. The search function is for if you don't know the device address - and it takes a while to do. In your case, presumably the addresses will never change. Find the addresses and hard-code them into your code. Or if that isn't practical, store them in EEPROM. And if even that isn't practical find the addresses once in setup.

---

Next, you need a delay while you take the temperature readings. Why not parallel those up? In a loop, tell all the devices to take a reading. Then wait one second. Then read them all (in another loop). That way the one-second delay is shared between all your sensors.

However from [the page Gerben linked](http://milesburton.com/Main_Page?title=Dallas_Temperature_Control_Library):

> And it is NOT possible to run DS1820 sensors on a simple pull-up resistor. During the "Conversion" phase, it needs more power. And there are Application Note discussing this in length.

That suggest that if you are using parasitic power, my suggestion won't work too well (having multiple devices taking readings would make it worse).

---

I found this code on my disk from a couple of years ago. There don't seem to be any delays between reading sensors. There is a delay at the end of the main loop, mainly to stop spamming the serial monitor.

Notice the comment:

> Call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature request to all devices on the bus

See if that works for you.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Streaming.h>

// Data wire is plugged into port 10 on the Arduino
const byte ONE_WIRE_BUS = 10;
const byte TEMPERATURE_PRECISION = 10;
// Setup a oneWire instance to communicate with any OneWire devices (not just Maxim/Dallas temperature ICs)
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);

// Pass our oneWire reference to Dallas Temperature. 
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// arrays to hold device addresses
DeviceAddress myThermometer [10];
int deviceCount;

void setup(void)
{

  // start serial port
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial << "Dallas Temperature IC Control Library Demo" << endl;

  // Start up the library
  sensors.begin();

  // locate devices on the bus
  Serial << "Locating devices..." << endl;
  deviceCount = sensors.getDeviceCount();

  Serial << "Found " << deviceCount << " devices." << endl;

  // report parasite power requirements
  Serial << "Parasite power is: " << (sensors.isParasitePowerMode() ? "ON" : "OFF") << endl; 

  // method 1: by index

  for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
  {
    if (sensors.getAddress(myThermometer [i], i))
    { 
      Serial << "Device " << i << " Address: ";
      printAddress(myThermometer [i]);
      Serial << endl;
      sensors.setResolution(myThermometer [i], TEMPERATURE_PRECISION);
    }
    else
      Serial << "Unable to find address for Device " << i << endl;
  }  // end of for loop

}

// function to print a device address
void printAddress(DeviceAddress deviceAddress)
{
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    // zero pad the address if necessary
    if (deviceAddress[i] < 16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(deviceAddress[i], HEX);
  }
}


void loop(void)
{ 

  // call sensors.requestTemperatures() to issue a global temperature 
  // request to all devices on the bus
  sensors.requestTemperatures();

  // now get all temperatures
  for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++)
  {
    float tempC = sensors.getTempC(myThermometer [i]);
    if (tempC > -80)
    { 
      Serial << "Device " << i << " Temperature: " << tempC << endl;
    }
    else
      Serial << "Unable to find temperature for Device " << i << endl;
  }  // end of for loop

  delay (1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm not using parasitic power, but my attempts at doing the readings in parallel failed-  possibly because my C skills are not great and partially because I am having difficulty understanding how the code works - or maybe it just can't be done.   Scanning the sensors on startup may be worthwhile doing at this point, but I deliberately scanned them in each loop so I could "hot plug" changes.

Comment: Look in the datasheet for using a "strong pullup" to supply extra current to to parasitically powered sensors. In my devices, I use an extra output port connected so as to bypass the pullup resistor (weak pullup), as a strong pullup. The datasheet shows an output port switching a transistor acting as the strong pullup. In practice, I've found that the port by itself sources enough current for 3 (the max I've tested) DS18b20 devices.

Comment: See amended post with another example.

Answer (score 0):

In case the "Temperature Conversion Time (tCONV)" of each resolution is not fast enough ([MAX] 9-bit: 93.75ms; 10-bit: 187.5ms; 11-bit resolution: 375ms; 12-bit: 750ms), you can use more sensors.

For example, to get a half time (for 9-bit): 47ms:

- You can use two sensors at the same measurement point, (they can operate in parallel , as long as the software can operate with each one of them) when reading one, the software starts converting the other.

Each one has its normal conversion time, but when doing the readings in an interleaved way, a shorter reading time can be obtained.

For 8 sensors, a time below 11.75ms can be achieved (for 9-bit).